# what is cache.cfg file meant for? can we git ignore this file

Tags: magento-enterprise, git

Why is the magento/downloader/cache.cfg file used for? can I ignore that file in the gitignore file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe to ignore this in your `.gitignore`. I normally have the following:

```
# Ignore downloader cache and configuration files
/downloader/.cache/
/downloader/cache.cfg
/downloader/connect.cfg
```

As for the `cache.cfg` file, this contains a gziped, PHP serialized array that contains all the current configuration information for you Magento Connect instance. This is where it stores extension versions.

source: [Where does Magento Connect track installed packages and versions?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19691/where-does-magento-connect-track-installed-packages-and-versions)

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to ignore cache.cfg if you ever use `./mage upgrade` or magento connect to keep track of packages. `.gitignore`. If you are just rsyncing to a server, then yes, the entire downloader folder can be left behind. But for development, you should share it, just like you would a package.json or a composer.lock.

```
# Ignore downloader cache, but not cache.cfg
/downloader/.cache/
```

`/downloader/cache.cfg` and `/downloader/connect.cfg` contain configuration details about what version the packages you downloaded are on. While it's easy to recover it, it's better to keep it in version control.

source:

```
$ ./mage list-installed
Installed package for channel 'community' :
Fooman_SpeedsterAdvanced 0.8.14 beta         
Fooman_Common        1.2.8 stable        
$ rm downloader/cache.cfg 
$ ./mage list-installed
No installed packages
```