# Removing manually updated extension from Magento Connect List (cosmetic fix)

Tags: magento-connect

Hi we want to remove an extension fom the Magento Connect list. Situation is

1. we installed via magento connect
2. since last year we updated this spec. plugin via FTP/zip file
3. but the magento connect keeps showing the "old" version

How can we remove the listing in magento connect? (maybe without actually touching any files, because everything works fine). I understand it is cosmetic only.

thanks!

Comment: You can check here - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19691/where-does-magento-connect-track-installed-packages-and-versions .

Comment: Thx. Read it. Any idea how we can easily remove it from the list?

Comment: What happens when you uninstall??? Does it actually remove all the files?

Comment: You can try to unset the element from the array `$unserialized` with key that is equal to your extension name and then save it back. Yes, it actually deletes all the files.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. So no shortcut here. Actually have to script it.